# A verb that describes someone limply falling into a sitting position

Tags: single-word-requests

In my writing, I have a character who, after a brief and sudden firefight, limply sits where she is standing. Normally, I would describe this as:

> Karen limply fell to the ramp.

This makes it sound like she toppled over unconscious. So I tried:

> Karen limply sat on the ramp.

This is better, but it sounds too much like she is in control of her position. She's sitting more out of shock than anything else. So I tried this:

> Karen limply fell to a sitting position on the ramp.

Which is more accurate, but a bit too long and technical for the context. It also has contradictory verbs, indicating both controlled and uncontrolled motion.

**Is there is single word I can use instead of 'fell to a sitting position'?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slump.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slump?s=t

to drop or fall heavily; collapse:
to assume a slouching, bowed, or bent position or posture:

Answer (score 1):

I suggest "crumpled" or "crumpled in place".

*Crumpled* suggests external weight being applied that forces the crumpling, which could be emotional weight. After a firefight there could be some heavy emotions involved, e.g. if deaths occurred. However, relief that it's over would be the most likely emotion, and *slumped* is the better choice for that.

Answer (score 1):

Flop :  fall, move, or hang in a heavy, loose, and ungainly way.

He was so tired, he just flopped into his chair.

It also has a nice onomatopoeic sound to it.

Edit: Added the following per the comments.

In all dictionaries references, Flop is an intransitive verb with the following definitions.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/flop
to fall or drop heavily

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flop
1. To fall or lie down heavily and noisily: flop onto the sofa.

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/flop_1
1: to sit or lie down in a heavy way by relaxing your muscles and letting your body fall

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flop
2:  to throw or move oneself in a heavy, clumsy, or relaxed manner

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flop
1. to fall or plump down suddenly, especially with noise; drop or turn with a sudden bump or thud (sometimes followed by down):

The puppy flopped down on the couch.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/flop
1. [no object] Fall, move, or hang in a heavy, loose, and ungainly way: 
black hair flopped across his forehead

1.1 Sit or lie down heavily or suddenly in a specified place, especially when very tired: 
Liz flopped down into the armchair

Comment: You ought to link to a dictionary definition of "flop." People are sometimes accused of plagiarism on here when they don't link to the definition.

Answer (score 1):

**plop (down)** (v.)

> To allow the body to drop heavily—usually used with *down*
>
> *plopped down on the couch* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plop)

> Of a person, etc.: to sit or lie down heavily or exhaustedly
> (frequently with *down*). OED